# Crear <TR> table con id automatico Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola buena tengo el siguiente codigo :
Mi idea es que al llamar a esta funcion inserte una fila en una tabla y para operar sobre ella ponerle un id al TR, que lo genero con la variable contador , el problema es que tengo asignada la id...pero no me coge valor (la variable si, pero al asignarlo no), si alguien sabe donde esta el fallo...Gracias!!

```js
<script>
    var contador=5;
    
    function createContact(){
            contador++;
            var mitabla = document.getElementById("tableContact");
        
            var elementos = mitabla.rows.length;
            var row =mitabla.insertRow(elementos);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            
            cell1.innerHTML = '<tr id='contador'><input type="text" size="8" name="name" id="name" size="12">';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="telef" id="telef" size="12">';
            cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="12" name="cargo" id="cargo" size="12">';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="email" id="email"size="12">'; 
            cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="emailC" id="emailC" value="1">';
            cell6.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="10" name="usuario" id="usuario" size="12">';
            cell7.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="coment" id="coment" size="12">';
            cell8.innerHTML = '<img onclick=modificarContacto(this); src="../graphics/edita1.jpg" height="20" width="20"><img onclick=eliminarContacto(this);  src="../graphics/delete12.jpg" height="20" width="20"><img onclick=saveContact(this);  src="../graphics/save123.jpg" height="20" width="20"></tr>';
           
                            }
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no tienes que crear el `tr` en `cell1.innerHTML`.

Quita eso y asigna el `id` a la `row` creada con `insertRow`:

```
row.setAttribute("id", contador);
```

Quedaría algo así:

```
var row =mitabla.insertRow(elementos);   
            row.setAttribute("id", contador);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);

            cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="name" id="name" size="12">';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="telef" id="telef" size="12">';
            cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="12" name="cargo" id="cargo" size="12">';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="email" id="email"size="12">'; 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero esta línea

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<tr id='contador'><input type="text" size="8" name="name" id="name" size="12">';
```

esta mal aqui no tienes que poner tr, ya que la fila se esta creando con:

```
var row =mitabla.insertRow(elementos);
```

Si quieres asignar el id al tr lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente:

```
row.id = contador
```

Espero que te sirva

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando llamas a la funcion `insertRow()`, esta ya te crea el `tr`, por lo que no es necesario que lo agreges en el siguiente innerHTML.

A la hora de crear la fila, utilizando `insertRow()` se lo asignas a una variable, por lo tanto puedes asignarle una `id` directamente.

```js
var contador=5;
    
    function createContact(){
            contador++;
            var mitabla = document.getElementById("tableContact");
        
            var elementos = mitabla.rows.length;
            var row =mitabla.insertRow(elementos);
            row.id = contador;
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            
            cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="name" id="name" size="12">';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="telef" id="telef" size="12">';
            cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="12" name="cargo" id="cargo" size="12">';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="8" name="email" id="email"size="12">'; 
            cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="emailC" id="emailC" value="1">';
            cell6.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="10" name="usuario" id="usuario" size="12">';
            cell7.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="coment" id="coment" size="12">';
            cell8.innerHTML = '<img onclick=modificarContacto(this); src="../graphics/edita1.jpg" height="20" width="20"><img onclick=eliminarContacto(this);  src="../graphics/delete12.jpg" height="20" width="20"><img onclick=saveContact(this);  src="../graphics/save123.jpg" height="20" width="20">';
            
            }
```

```html
<table id="tableContact">

</table>
```

Comment: Tampoco me lo detecta..

Comment: Se genera la celda? si es asi, que id te aparece en ese `tr` ?

Comment: Sisi generar se me genera todo correctamente!, ninguna id como si no tuviera...

Comment: Ya esta la solución, edito la respuesta.